# Backbone Login Verification

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm asking this question in part for a whole class. We are having a hard time getting a token for login. Also, if you guys don't mind, tells us how we can improve our question asking skills.

"I am trying to use my API to assign the account we are logging in as with a token. I've tried various things, but nothing really seems to work. What needs to be sent to the URL for the token to be generated looks like this:

```
{
  "grant_type": "password",
  "username": "user@example.com",
  "password": "password"
}
```

Then we need to be able to receive the token so that we can do some things with that account. Could anybody push me in the right direction to accomplish this? Also want to add - do we need a model and collection for our token?

Our Goal is to be able to retrieve a token, so that after we create a user we can login into our app on the login page.

```
// User Model and Collection. Used to input user data.
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "https://twitterapii.herokuapp.com/users"
});

//Collection for when we GET data from API
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User,
    url: "https://twitterapii.herokuapp.com/users",

    parse: function(response) {
        return response.data;
    }
})

//Collection for when we GET data from API
var UsersTokens = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User,
    url: "https://twitterapii.herokuapp.com/oauth/token",

    parse: function(response) {
        return response.data;
    }
})  


var signinView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'section',
    template: _.template($('#signInTemplate').html()),
    events: {
        "click .signinButton": 'handleLoginClick'
    },
    send: function(){
        var signin = this.$('.signinButton').val();
        console.log("clicking!!");
        var email = this.$(".email").val();
        var password = this.$(".password").val();
        logUser: UsersTokens.fetch( {
            headers: {
                grant_type: password,
                username: email,
                password: password
        } });
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template());
    },
    handleLoginClick: function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.send();
        console.log("login clicksss!!");
    }
});
```

Comment: I would rephrase "want" with my goal is, this is what I have tried for this goal.

Comment: I dont fully understand your intent. So you want to login, with those attributes and then receive a token, then use the token as a logged user, is that it?